# Angular 5: Using 3rd party scripts doesn't work in <div *ngIf="something">

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am currently integrating a 3rd party library into an Angular component. The component is dependent on a script which i load in the contructor:

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.loadAPI = new Promise(resolve => {
        this.loadScript();
        resolve(true);
    });
}

public loadScript() {
    let isFound = false;
    const scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
        if (
            scripts[i].getAttribute('src') != null &&
            scripts[i].getAttribute('src').includes('loader')
        ) {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if (!isFound) {
        const dynamicScripts = [
            'https://some.script.js',
        ];

        for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
            const node = document.createElement('script');
            node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
            node.type = 'text/javascript';
            node.async = false;
            node.charset = 'utf-8';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the component and the 3rd party library is defined in the root of the markup - it works fine:

```
<div class="3rd-party" data-locale="something" data-template-id="id" data-businessunit-id="businessunit-id" data-style-height="240px" data-style-width="100%">
</div>
```

however, if I want the element to be in a *ngIf div, so it's only visible upon an event, it doesn't show:

```
<div *ngIf="isSliderOpen">
  <div class="3rd-party" data-locale="something" data-template-id="id" data-businessunit-id="businessunit-id" data-style-height="240px" data-style-width="100%">
</div>
```

Why does this happen? and how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the way to go. You might want to have a look at Angular's built-in lazy loading feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the `[hidden]` tag in the markup instead of the *ngIf

as @trichetriche pointed out this is probably due to the div never being processed. By using the hidden tag this is avoided